# 0xc0000374 Heap Corruption in Cli/Cpp code when debugging is not attched

Tags: c++, opencv

I am running into a problem with a Heap Corruption in my Cli/cpp project.

Things only seem to give issues when a debugger is not attached or not profiling using dependency walker tools.

It seems to me that the application is first crashing at the end when freeing up some memory.

If anyone could take a look at tell me if I am doing something really bad in the following code that could cause this.

```
std::string imagePath = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(Path::Combine(this->context->WorkingDirectory, this->context->Payload->ImagePath));
std::cout << imagePath << std::endl;
cv::Mat image = cv::imread(imagePath);

if (!image.data)
{
    throw gcnew System::Exception("image data is not loaded");
}


std::vector<cv::Point2f> src;
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, image.rows));
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(image.cols, image.rows));
src.push_back(cv::Point2f(image.cols, 0));

cv::Mat M = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst);

cv::Mat warp_img((ymax - ymin + 1)*tileSize, (xmax - xmin + 1)*tileSize, CV_8UC3);



std::vector<cv::Point2f> obj_corners(4);
obj_corners[0] = cv::Point(0, 0); obj_corners[1] = cv::Point(image.cols, 0);
obj_corners[2] = cv::Point(image.cols, image.rows); obj_corners[3] = cv::Point(0, image.rows);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> scene_corners(4);

cv::perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, M);

cv::warpPerspective(image, warp_img, M, cv::Size((xmax - xmin + 1)*tileSize, (ymax - ymin + 1)*tileSize));
image.release();


cv::Mat warp_img_fliped;
cv::flip(warp_img, warp_img_fliped, 0);
warp_img.release();

String^ id = Guid::NewGuid().ToString();

std::vector<int> compression_params;
if (this->context->Payload->Extension->Equals(".png")){
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9);

}
if (this->context->Payload->Extension->Equals(".jpg")){
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(this->context->Payload->Quality);

}

for (int r = 0, rr = (ymax - ymin + 1)*tileSize, ty_idx = ymax; r < rr; r += tileSize, ty_idx--){
    for (int c = 0, cc = (xmax - xmin + 1)*tileSize, tx_idx = xmin; c < cc; c += tileSize, tx_idx++)
    {
        std::cout << ty_idx << " " << tx_idx << std::endl;

        cv::Mat tile = warp_img_fliped(cv::Rect(c, r, tileSize, tileSize)); 

        String^ Path = Path::Combine(this->context->WorkingDirectory, id,String::Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}", zoom,tx_idx,ty_idx, this->context->Payload->Extension));
        Directory::CreateDirectory(Path::GetDirectoryName(Path));               
        std::string path = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >(Path);
        cv::imwrite(path, tile, compression_params);
    }
}
warp_img_fliped.release();
```

Comment: Minor help: Check for class members which are not initialized in ctor. (This might be obvious)

Comment: nothing is obvious right now :)

Comment: Another point: Make sure you are not mixing debug with release libs. I don't know why, but I observed a tendency of doing this when working with CV

Answer (score 1):

So the error was even before the code I posted above.

by taking one line at a time and returning I was able to find the cause of my heap corruption.

```
double pxpy[2] = { (double)xmin * tileSize, (double)ymin * tileSize };  
pixelsToMeters(pxpy, zoom, initialResolution, mxmy);
```

above works and below was causing the error

```
pixelsToMeters(new double[] { (double)xmin * tileSize, (double)ymin * tileSize }, zoom, initialResolution, mxmy);
```